# Xcode - localizable.strings - not always working

Tags: xcode, localization

I've developed quite a large project, but now I'm getting a silly issue all the time.

My localizations aren't always localized. Every second build they fail. Is this a known Xcode bug?

I'm running the latest version of Xcode.

Comment: When you say "aren't always localised", what do you mean?  The build doesn't do the localization does it, it simply copies the localised files into the Application bundle.  Have to checked if one or more localized files aren't being copied correctly?

Comment: hello, thanks for the answer. Yes, the problem is, that these files are only copied once everv second build. This is not really anoying but one of my latest apps got into the appstore without the localization files and this was really anoying.

Comment: Hmmm, I've never seen that issue myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably because there are two `localizable.strings` files in your solution. It can easily happen if you drop in source files from another project (e.g. ShareKit). See this other question for an explanation and a solution: [Localisation strings not always work having ShareKit in a project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747436/localisation-strings-not-always-work-having-sharekit-in-a-project/7747614#7747614)