# iOS how to localize files in for a module

Tags: iphone, ios, localization, internationalization, translation

I have a class that implements the "Take photo / Choose from library" that we all know and love. It is here https://github.com/fulldecent/FDTake This is included in my other projects via git submodule and that works fine.

Now I need to translate the text in that class to Chinese so it is "拍照 / 选照片" or something like that. Is there a good way to put translations in there so everyone can use them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Localization is typically handled by the `NSLocalizedString(<#key#>, <#comment#>)` macro. In the source your replace all hard coded string with the macro. For example:

```
    [self.buttonTitles addObject:@"Hi"]; // hard coded greeting
```

with

```
    [self.theLabel setText:(NSLocalizedString(@"theKey", @"Hi"))];
```

Then `genstrings` (from inside a Terminal) is used to scan the implementations file (*.m) and to write its output to the language project folder (here: en.lproj)

```
    $ genstrings -o en.lproj/ *.m
```

In the directory `en.lproj/` a file called `Localizable.strings`. Its contents will be:

```
/* Hi */
"theKey" = "theKey";
```

The comment `/* Hi */` is taken from our source code. The string `Hi` should be  displayed to the (English speaking) user. So we need to edit the string on the right hand side of the equals sign and make it the greeting, `= "theKey"` has to become `= "Hi"`:

```
/* Hi */
"theKey" = "Hi!";
```

### So far so good

All this is fine if there are only a few strings or when there is no intend to ever modify the strings. The moment gestrings is run again it will overwrite the modifications and you effectively lose the work done in `Localizable.strings`. 
An idea could be to write the output of genstrings to a different location. But then you will have to manually merge the changes. Once the `Localizable.strings` file grows it becomes a nightmare trying to keep source code and `Localizable.strings` in sync. So lets try to avoid that.

A big help comes from using `NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(<#key#>, <#tbl#>, <#bundle#>, <#val#>, <#comment#>)`. This macro will allow to set a default value in the `Localizable.strings` file and in addition, it will make the need for the initial edit of the value field go away.

Putting it together:

```
[self.theLabel setText:NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(@"theKey2", @"Localizable", [NSBundle mainBundle], @"Hi!", @"informal greeting"))];
```

After running the `genstrings` command as used above there is now a small different in `Localizable.strings`

```
/* informal greeting */
"theKey2" = "Hi!";
```

Apart from the comment now telling the translator that we want an informal greeting, the `“Hi!”` is already present in the value filed. There is no need to go to the Localizable.strings file, search for the correct line, modify the field form “theKey” to “Hi!”. `genstrings` did that for us based on the default value supplied with NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue.

Add the file `Localizable.strings` to the xcode project.

### Doing the translations

After changing the source code, for a new language from inside the Xcode first add a localization to `Localizable.strings`. Xcode will generate a copy of `Localizable.strings` under a subfolder based on the original  `Localizable.strings`.

I personally don't speak Chinese, but German. So if to add German localization my translation would go under `de.lproj/Localizable.strings`, italian under `it.lproj/` and so on.

Edit the new `Localizable.strings` as needed:

(German)

```
/* informal greeting */
"theKey2" = "Hallo!";
```

(Italian)

```
/* informal greeting */
"theKey2" = "Ciao!";
```

and then build and run.

`********* begin edit`

### Bundle it up

The above considers a "standard" xcode project. You are asking about cereateing a module, therefore allowing your code to become an addition to a project. I suggest you create a bundle with the localizations. When somebody will include your code into their project the localizations remain separate. 
Full documentation about bundles is [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/corefoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH1-SW1).

A project that uses bundles for localizations is [QuincyKit](https://github.com/TheRealKerni/QuincyKit) (there probably are more, that one was the first that came to mind)

So when placing the localization into a bundle other than the `mainBundle` the `[NSBundle mainBundle]` in the line below has to change

```
    [self.theLabel setText:NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(@"theKey2", @"Localizable", [NSBundle mainBundle], @"Hi!", @"informal greeting"))];
```

Instead of getting the strings from the mainBundle, obtain a reference to your own module. The docs suggest:

```
    NSBundle* myBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
```

So the line becomes:

```
    [self.theLabel setText:NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(@"theKey2", @"Localizable", myBundle, @"Hi!", @"informal greeting"))];
```

`********* end edit`

---

PS: : [my original text can be seen here](http://www.greck.eu/blog/2011/11/27/translating-your-iphone-and-ipad-project/)

Comment: Thank you, and just to be sure, when I distribute this as a module, I will distribute the file `FDTakeController.h`, `FDTakeController.m`, and all the lproj folders right? It is ok for them to include my lproj folders and then have other lproj for the rest of their project's resources?

Comment: Please see my edits under "Bundle it up". Using a bundle will separate the localizations

Answer (score 1):

I think a bundle (as Olaf suggests) would work great, but another way with less overhead to ensure that your localizable string resources don't interfere with another project in the same solution ([causing a weird problem to people reusing your component in another localized project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493243/xcode-localizable-strings-not-always-working/10494956#10494956)) is to change your `localizable.strings` file name to a unique file name. This means that where you used `NSLocalizedString` you now need to use its variant `NSLocalizedStringFromTable` ([Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/miscellaneous/foundation_functions/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/macro/NSLocalizedStringFromTable)), where tableName is the same name as your strings file (without the .strings extension). You can define your own macro so that's it's just a straight replacement of `NSLocalizedString` with, say `FDTakeLocalizedString`.

A file name collision is much less likely to happen with XIBs files or storyboards than for the `localizable.strings` file. But in both cases, if you use a prefixed naming convention (say FDTake.strings and FDTake-Main.xib), it will eliminate the risk and can only help.

Comment: Just trying to understand the workflow. So I would ship FDTake.m, FDTake.h, FDTake.strings, and then a bunch of lproj folders: en.lproj/FDTake.strings, fr.lproj/FDTake.strings. Then for the users, they would drag the M and H into their project. And then they drag the strings files into each of their lproj folders, or do they drag my folders directly into their project?

Comment: The second option (drag your folders straight in--or in fact, just the parent folder of your subfolders) will work just fine. XCode doesn't care--you can have multiple lproj folders for a same language but in the end, in the app bundle built by XCode, they will all go into one lproj in the root folder.